# netty-socketio: How to keep WebSocket server alive when app is minimised

Tags: android, websocket, socket.io, android-lifecycle

I am recently working on a project that requires a WebSocket server running in Android. I come across netty-socketio, which can help to implement a WebSocket server as a part of an app. However, when the app is minimised by clicking the circle button, it is no longer alive. As a result, WebSocket clients cannot connect to it anymore.

I would like to keep the WebSocket server alive even the app is minimised, until the app is turned off. I am working on 5.1.1 Lollipop. Any possible solution or hint will be appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried reconnecting when onStart()?

Comment: Try to use ping pong mechanism. If your minimize app activity will not exist try to run a foreground service. ** mobile battery may effect if you run service for long time.

Comment: Hi Hasan, I haven't tried it yet. Will do more research about it.

Comment: Hi rajahskar, I don't worry about the battery because the device connects to power all the time.